# Altering Shipping/Billing address inline entity form

Tags: 8, commerce

Now that Drupal 8 Commerce moved to Inline Entity Form approach. I am having trouble of altering Address for fields for the checkout... In the past I could do this:

```
function hook_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {

  $element["address"] .........

}
```

Essentially I was adding couple extra classes to fields, adding placeholder attributors and adding couple of hidden fields... But now that we moved to InlineEntityForm I have trouble finding this....

I am trying at the moment of using `hook_inline_entity_form_table_fields_alter()` or `hook_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter()` but cannot seems to be able to do the same thing....

If anybody could point me to the right direction that would amazing.

Cheers,

Comment: Commerce uses the Inline Form API, that has nothing to do with the Inline Entity Form module, so the hooks in question are not invoked. hook_field_widget_form_alter() should still work

Comment: Cheers! I will try to debug this deeper...